# CollectionView reloadData() weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to make a Collection View with cells, where you can select the colors of my little game. Therefor you can choose between different themes (each in one cell). If the theme is unlocked (by achieving scores), the blur view and the lock-icon should disappear, and all available cells/ themes should be selectable. I implemented this like so:

(Collection ViewController Class:)

```
    import UIKit
import PMSuperButton

class myCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var backBtn: UIButton!
    
    let items = ["Default dot", "Trap your first dot", "Score 15 or less (classic)", "Score 5 or less (classic)", "Score 15 or less (hard)", "Score 25 or less (no chill)", "Score 15 or less (snake)", "Score 15 or less everywhere", "Score 10 or less everywhere", "Circle the dot 100 times", "10"]
    var preSelected = IndexPath()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateUnlockedString()
        updateColor()
    }
    
    func updateColor(){
        view.backgroundColor = myColors().selected(value: selectedInstance.selectedColor).backgroundColor
    }
    func   updateUnlockedString(){
        let easyHS = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highscoreeasy")
        let classicHS = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highscoreclassic")
        let hardHS = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highscorehard")
        let nochillHS = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highscoreno chill")
        let snakeHS = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "highscoresnake")
        
        var unlockedString = ""
        
        //unimportant steps deleted

        UserDefaults.standard.set(unlockedString, forKey: "unlocked")
        
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
        if(unlockInstance.unlockedString.contains(String(indexPath.item))){
            cell.unlockedEffect()
            print("unlocked Effect")
        }
        cell.label.text = items[indexPath.item]
        cell.removeHighlight()
        if indexPath.item == selectedInstance.selectedColor{
             cell.highlightEffect()
             preSelected = IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: indexPath.section)
         }
        cell.setupCellFilling(playerColor: myColors().selected(value: indexPath.item).playerColor, objColor: myColors().selected(value: indexPath.item).objColor, defaultColor: myColors().selected(value: indexPath.item).defaultColor, backgroundColor: myColors().selected(value: indexPath.item).backgroundColor)
         myCollectionView = collectionView
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        if ((collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell?) != nil) && unlockInstance.unlockedString.contains(String(indexPath.item)){
            selectedInstance.selectedColor = indexPath.item
            updateColor()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    @IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        cameInstance.came = true
    }
    
}
```

(Collection CELL Class:)

```
    import UIKit

class myCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lockedBlur: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lockedIcon: UIImageView!

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // cell rounded section
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        // cell shadow section
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.shadowColor = myColors().selected(value: selectedInstance.selectedColor).defaultColor.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
   

extension myCollectionViewCell{

   func highlightEffect(){
      self.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
      self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
   }

   func removeHighlight(){
      self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
   }
    func unlockedEffect(){
        lockedBlur.alpha = 0
        lockedIcon.alpha = 0
    }
    func setupCellFilling(playerColor: UIColor, objColor: UIColor, defaultColor: UIColor, backgroundColor: UIColor){
        
        lockedBlur.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
        blurView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterialDark)
        lockedIcon.tintColor = objColor
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
  
    }

}
```

**The problem**

When I open the CollectionView (viewDidLoad), everything appears 100% fine! All cells that should be locked, appear locked (lockedBlur.alpha = 0 and lockedIcon.alpha = 0). Also, only the locked cells are selectable, which I can see with the green border. Only the selected Cell has a green border, thats right.

BUT: When I select a cell, **some random locked cells loose their blur view and loose their lock-icon** (so blockedBlur and lockedIcon disappear). They still aren't selectable. Sometimes this affects all cells, sometimes only e.g. 2.

When I select a cell, the didSelectItemAt Function gets called. And this also calls updateColors() which only changes the background and calls the mysterious reloadData(). In my opinion the reloadData() SOMEHOW makes the lockedBlur and lockedIcon disappear, and I cannot find why....

Maybe someone can help me..

Thank you!!

SwiftHobby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on Fitness App which has pretty similar working CollectionView behavior for it's training plan section. Basically you select certain cell when you finish an exercise. So I played around a lot with way of implementing selecting and deselecting cells. As I see you are missing selecting and deselecting functions of CollectionViewDelegate. There you set different states Effects

Here is the functions you have to use:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
        cell.showIcon()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
        cell.hideIcon()
    }
}
```